# Multiple sliders, buttons controlling all sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, multiple-instances

I am trying to use this slider: http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl

I need to have multiple sliders on the page, up to 10 maybe more. It is for a property listings page, and this is a really light slider.

Currently when you press next, it slides the images for every slider. I know its an ID issue, but is there a simple way to fix this without having to have tens of different id's?

UPDATE!

This is my updated pen, with the sliders working: http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/LEKBa But it appears each slider is loading the last LI in UL

Comment: It should be a pretty easy fix. In the click event for the `next` and `prev` buttons pass the `parent` into the function then use that to do the animation. It will limit the scope to only the slider that's being used.

Comment: You can fix it yes, but it's a quick fix. You'd need to change the jQuery (and CSS) to use a class instead of ID, plus it would need to then refer to the individual instance being clicked, whereas now it refers to a specific ID.

Comment: @Shaded Yeh, my only concern is the id #slider has styling to it. could you be more specific? I just want to avoid having a new duplicate styles for each slider.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, I'l give that a try.

Comment: You could turn this into a jQuery plugin with a little work and then use it everywhere easily.

Comment: the ID slider has styling to it, the simple fix would be to change that CSS rule to target a class instead. It's recommended that you don't target ID's in CSS anyway.

Comment: I changed everything to classes, still ever image slides when you press next.

Comment: every element needs to be unique. If there's multiple sliders that match your selector, the event to advance to the next slide will be called on all of them. Either use unique selectors per slider, or update your click event to use the parent of the click event.

Comment: @AndrewTran This was my original thought. How can I get around this without having to create an class/id for each slider?

Comment: @AndrewTran - Who says that you shouldn't target IDs in CSS?

Comment: It seems I'm going to need to duplicate this entire pen, and give it a different ID for every slider. unless anyone knows a better way? :P

Comment: @j08691 let me rephrase, you shouldn't target ID's in css unless that element is a singleton

Comment: @AndrewTran - I don't understand what you mean by that. All IDs must be singletons by definition.

Comment: they *should* be. in OP's use case, they're very clearly not. he's writing a CSS rule that he's intending to style multiple elements. Whenever you are intending a CSS rule to match multiple elements, using an ID selector is not correct.

Comment: So with everything as Classes like it should be. There needs to be a way on the next/prev function to only change the selected slider. a friend mentioned the `this` function. any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking something like this...

```
function moveRight(slider) {
    slider = $(slider);
    slider.find('ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        slider.find('ul li:first-child').appendTo(slider.find('ul'));
        slider.find('ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    moveRight($(this).parent());
});
```

Makes it so that the only global selection is `a.control_next` and then the rest are scoped to where the click actually happened.

EDIT: There are some additional issues with selecting more than you want. Here's another fixed spot.

This

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
```

Becomes this

```
$('.slider').each(function(slider){
  slider = $(slider);
  slider.find('ul li:last-child').prependTo(slider.find('ul'));
});
```

This takes the last image in each slider and prepends it to the list so the back button will work. You will run into additional issues if the picture width/height/count differ or if you choose to implement the checkbox autoscroll.

To fix those though you would need to implement a much better structure in the js so that each slider has it's own variables. I don't really have the time to go through and set that up, sorry.

Comment: OH nice! thats kind of working. I am able to slide individual sliders now. The only thing is I think all images are being loaded at the same time. not the specific ones in the UL.

Comment: @LukeD1uk I don't really understand what you mean about the images loading. Can you give me an example?

Comment: As you can see here: http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/LEKBa  It is loading all images into each slider.

Comment: It looks to me like its loading the last `li` in each `ul` I don't understand why...

Comment: @LukeD1uk it's putting the last image before the first so that the back button will work on initial load. I wrapped that in a jquery each so that it's scoped properly, I'll update the answer shortly.