# Multiple image slider loading images wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, slider

If you take a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/LEKBa You will see my sliders are loading the last `LI` of all `UL` and displaying them in each slider. Obviously its not supposed to do this; anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on another questions I posted related to this issue.

This:

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
```

Becomes this

```
$('.slider').each(function(slider){
  slider = $(slider);
  slider.find('ul li:last-child').prependTo(slider.find('ul'));
});
```

Original Question: [Multiple sliders, buttons controlling all sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370661/multiple-sliders-buttons-controlling-all-sliders)

Answer (score 1):

You are grabbing the last child li and prepending it

```
$('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');
```

Remove line 19 in your CodePen and add e.preventDefault() like below to keep the page from jumping to the top

```
$('a.control_prev').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    moveLeft($(this).parent());
});

$('a.control_next').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    moveRight($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @joshboley This my questions was answered just as I asked this question. :)